# Kendo UI command not recognizing the function "Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'"

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have created a KendoUI grid inside template and have to add custom commands to the grid.The data is being filled by view model . but when I am running the code it is not able to find the function mentioned in the js file. i tried to move the function in and out of kendo.observable scope but it still give me error " Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'"

```
    <div id="vList" data-role="grid"
         data-scrollable="false"
         data-sortable="false"
         data-editable="false"
         data-columns="[
                            { command: { text: 'URL', click: 'getURL'}, title: ' ', width: '110px' },
                            { 'field': 'name', 'width': 150, 'title': 'Value' },
                            { 'field': 'description', 'title': 'Description' }]"
         data-bind="source: vList">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I too have had trouble with this, and have relegated handling that event elsewhere with something like $("#vList").delegate("tbody>tr .commandButtonClass", "click", function(e) { ... });

Comment: Hi Robin, did that worked and if yes then in my example what will be in place of  .commandButtonClass

Comment: Messed that up slightly, it uses className inside the command item.  Here is a working sample of what I have been doing to get around this.  http://jsbin.com/fahegu/2/edit?js,console,output

Comment: thanks Robin but unfortunately it didn't worked for me. I am passing datasource to a template which is having the grid.